# Creating a experiment where participants generate their own tests from a list of key terms

Tags: java

I am looking to run an experiment and am hoping to do so through a computer program that I am anticipating creating; however, I am (very) fairly new at programming and am hoping to get some help.

Here is what I need...

I need to create a program that starts out by giving participants a paper that they will read for 20 minutes. After these 20 minutes, I need the program to move on to the next page which gives participants a list of say 10 words. On this page, I ask participants to choose 5 of these words. Participants have 5 minutes and cannot move on to the next page of return to the previous page. From here, I want the program to generate a test from multiple choice questions that I have already created, I guess in a database. I want the program to randomly pick 3 questions from the database that are linked to the 5 words the participants have chosen and 1 question from the 5 words that the participants did not choose. The test would then consist of 20 questions. Participants would take this test 10 minutes after they had chosen and submitted the 5 words; during these 10 minutes, I want the paper that was at the beginning of the program to appear. After ten minutes, participants would then have 25 minutes to complete the generated test. This will then complete this participant’s participation.

I have another idea that could be added to this but I wanted to see if this was a plausible idea before I moved on.

Is there a program that I can use to set this idea up in this way or will I need to learn some programming basics in order to obtain this?

I am not sure what tag to include with this post so I just added (naively) java, I hope this doesn't cause any issues.

Thank you for your time!
Julia

Comment: This is, more or less, a software design matter.  You want to storyboard your program, and simulate what the users would see and do. Write use cases and draw mock-ups of your UI.  Once you have that, write specifications on how each interaction is supposed to behave and look.  After that, one (or a team) can write code.  There are professional software design tools available for thousands of dollars, but what I've described happens in small teams with a whiteboard and many different colors of ink. (Which is bad in practice, but a start.)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 bits...  I don't think you will find anything out of the box for your 'problem'. The test is not complicated to program, but obviously will require knowledge for programming. Or have someone build this for you.  You could build this in pretty much any language including java.

I am sorry I can't be of much more help here.

Comment: I disagree in that it *requires* programming knowledge.  This reads more like a specification from a client.  I'm also leery of the choice of language; there's no guarantee that Java would be ideal for this sort of interactive presentation - Flex or Javascript seem more ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Julia. Maybe there are software products on internet that could have an approach like the one you have described here, in that case I recommend you to start browsing **e-learning** tools.

If there are no products that gives you what you need (or maybe something that will fulfill your needs), then you could download an open source and give the work to adapt it to your needs or another scenario where you have to make one by yourself ("by yourself" means you should do the code or maybe hire someone to do it). If you're not very experienced with programming (as it looks) and you have the budget then it would be better to hire someone who could do make it, in the "worst" case (when programming or software is not your main line of business) you can learn some programming and start making the application (I insist this one is not a good idea).

Another thing, based on your question, the Java language is not the only option, the program can be done in another language and platform (standalone application, web application) but that depends on your needs.